# Software design: How to store different types of content in a database

Tags: php, laravel, database-schema, software-design, data-access

I'm building an laravel web app where I want users to create albums and put stuff in the albums. That stuff they can put in an album would mainly be images, but also texts, youtube video's, soundcloud tracks, and more (to come). Every piece of content would be an item in an album.

**My 'solution'**:
I have an album table and a content table. The content table rows are all the pieces of content I want to store. I thought of creating a content_meta table with a foreign key to the content table (which in turn has a foreign key to the album table). the content table has information on the type of content being stored (image, video, text, youtube video) and the content_meta table has all the info for each piece of content.

For example an image has a row in the content table:

```
id   | album_id | user_id | content_type
------------------------------ 
1231 | 311      | 973     | image
```

and that image has the following content_meta table rows

```
id   | content_id | meta_option | meta_value
-------------------------------------------
1231 | 1231       | thumb_url   | http://example.com/img/1231/thumb.jpg
1231 | 1231       | full_url    | http://example.com/img/1231/thumb.jpg
1231 | 1231       | description | what an image this is!
```

My question is **How to store these pieces of content in the database 'the right way'?**. The solution I came up with, is it scalable (for many albums and many users)? Will it be easy to add more content types in the future?

I am by no means an expert on web app architecture/design as I am a self-taught 'developer'. I really want to learn how to do things properly!

In many real life examples I came across a different solution where I saw images being stored in a media table. But then, how would I store a youtube video for example? Would I create a different table for all different content types I want to store (tables for images, videos, Youtube videos, Soundcloud songs, etc...)?

Or should I create a media (for images and videos) table and a content table (for saving texts and pieces of html, like youtube videos?)?

In my application you would only post one content type per album item. Not like on Facebook where you would post an image with some text!

You would really help me out by giving me advice on how to tackle this dilemma!

Comment: I advise you against using the EAV (Entity Attribute Value) model, it is considered an anti-pattern

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use of polymorphism. You can you a table to store different types of media. The morph table would store the models media types etc.

Read the docs here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Also to get you in the groove Jeffery Way has a good video on it: https://laracasts.com/lessons/polymorphic-huh

And Adam Wathan done a nice cast on it recent: http://adamwathan.me/2015/09/03/pushing-polymorphism-to-the-database/